# How can I check if my cronjob is runnning on my server via PHP?

Tags: cron, php

I would like to give out a warning If cron is not running or if a certain cronjob is not set in crontab on my server.

Is this possible to check with php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the output of `crontab -l` to see if a particular crontab entry is present or not. As for if `cron` is running or not, you can parse the output of a `ps -eaf` command to see if `crond` is running or not.

```
$ ps -eaf|grep [c]rond
root      1705     1  0 May27 ?        00:00:03 crond
```

The output from `crontab -l` would be something like this:

```
$ crontab -l
0 12 * * * ls
```

NOTE: You can use the [`system()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) in PHP to call command line tools or [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

#### EDIT #1

Based on your comment you could do the following from PHP. My script, `cronstatus.php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
exec("PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin; service crond status", $out, $ret);
print $ret . "\n";
?>
```

#### example run

```
$ sudo service crond stop
Stopping crond:                                            [  OK  ]
$ ./cronstatus.php 
3

$ sudo service crond start
Starting crond:                                            [  OK  ]
$ ./cronstatus.php 
0
```

The function `exec` can return the output of the command to a variable, `$out` and the results of the status returned by the command it executed in `$ret`.

Comment: So how would I call these inside PHP to show the result on a website?

Comment: `$last_line = system('ls', $retval);` or `echo exec('whoami');`

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: this works: `exec("PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin; service cron status")` It shows the status if cron is running at least

Comment: Just a mention here: allowing PHP to do stuff like "exec" and "system" is a huge security concern. This, among others, should be listed under "disable_funtions = " in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

If PHP can probably read the contents of `/etc/crontab` but normally not the contents of `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` you would have to parse the lines, primarily skiping commented out entries (is that what you mean with 'a certain cronjob is not set in crontab'?).

Checking whether there is a 'cron' entry in the process table should be possible, but figuring out if it actually doing something or not maybe more difficult.

On an old, somewhat unstable machine machine I had inherited, `cron` would sometimes die. I had setup an task that would run every 15 minutes, notifying another more reliable machine (via email). That other machine would run a cronjob as well checking if an email had arrived less than 15 minutes ago. If not that job would sent me a notice on my pager. So I would only get a message when cron was dead, not every 15 minutes.

You could setup something similar if you have a second machine to work with. The email message can contain the contents of any crontab file (even from `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`) and can check if the necessary command is still included.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and portable solution would to check the timestamp of a file that you create by cron especially for this purpose.

Create a cronjob that touches a file each minute readeable by the webbrowser, for example:

```
* * * * *   www-data touch /var/www/cron-testfile
```

and check the timestamp with php:

```
<?php
if(time() - filemtime('/var/www/cron-testfile') > 600) {
   echo "warning, cron not running";
}
?>
```